# How to get a subset of Rows from a DataTable object

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable object and I only want to take a subset of the rows. 
I've tried creating a temp table through a DataView object (since i need to sort it) but when I try to clear the first table, the rows from the temp table are also deleted...

my C# code

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv = myTable.DefaultView;

string sortString = sortField;

if (sortOrder == SortOrder.ascending)   
{
    sortString += " ASC"; 
}
else
{
    sortString += " DESC";
}
dv.Sort = sortString;

DataTable sortedTable = dv.ToTable();

myTable = sortedTable;

myTable.Rows.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < PageSize; i++)
{
     myTable.Rows.Add(sortedTable.Rows[((page - 1) * PageSize) + i]);
}
```

Comment: You can [select](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select) from a datatable

Comment: I need a subset relative to order, there's really no conditions i need other than from a table of 100 rows, give me rows 56-70... now row 34-48... it's data independent, i just need whatever is at the specified inices, that's why i'm sorting it

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a copy and storing it in sortedTable:

```
DataTable sortedTable = dv.ToTable();
```

OK. But then you say:

```
myTable = sortedTable;
```

At this point, `myTable` and `sortedTable` are referring to the same object. And then you say, "OK. take the copy I just created and clear all the rows in it.

```
myTable.Rows.Clear();
```

Just remove:

```
myTable = sortedTable;
```

and everything else should be fine.

Well, you also need to use:

```
myTable.ImportRow
```

not `myTable.Rows.Add`, otherwise .NET will complain that the row already belongs to another table.